# How can you tell the type of encoding being used?

Tags: encoding

`$2y$05$68LWs2pXiEvhVTacJ9PX/elfa1zq9jCBlv61hEw1pCvAHlaJyeMwW`

This hash value is 70 characters long. How can I tell what type of encoding was used to generate it? Also, how many bits does each character hold?

Comment: It looks crypt-formatted. [This documentation page](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html) will probably help you.

Answer (score 4):

That looks like bcrypt.

There are four parts:

- `$2y` - identifier that this is bcrypt in modular crypt format.
- `$05` - number of key expansion rounds: in this case, it is 2<sup>5</sup>
- `68LWs...X/e` - this is the salt. A total of 128 bits encoded in base64.
- `lfa1z...MwW` - this is the hash. A total of 184 bits encoded in base64.

Since base64 encodes three bytes to four base64 characters, you get 6 bits for each base64 character.

Comment: +1, but three bytes encode to four characters (3*8/6) not six.

Comment: @Rup Oh right! I was probably thinking six bits!